# Date's difference using diff()

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I group a dataframe based on the fields 'MachineName', 'LocalIPAddress' and then find the difference between consecutive dates of each group.

```
df2 = df.groupby(['MachineName', 'LocalIPAddress', 'DateTime'])['DateTime'].agg(
     ['count']).reset_index()
df2['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['DateTime'])
df2['timedif'] = df2['DateTime'].diff()
```

It works well for first group, but for second group, it does not start from the beginning, rather it subtracts the DateTime from the DateTime of its previous record which is of a different group.

Sample Data:

```
  MachineName LocalIPAddress DateTime count timedif
0 BMTSAFT04 10.18.0.186 2016-04-13 03:42:29.865 1 NaT
1 BMTSAFT04 10.18.0.186 2016-04-13 08:48:33.005 1 05:06:03.140000
2 BMTSAFT04 10.18.0.186 2016-04-13 10:16:28.612 1 01:27:55.607000
3 BMTSAFT04 10.18.0.186 2016-04-13 10:31:33.343 1 00:15:04.731000
4 BMTSAFT04 10.18.0.186 2016-04-13 23:43:12.068 1 13:12:56.580000
5 BMTSYSP05 10.20.9.253 2016-04-13 06:08:53.584 1 -1 day +06:25:41
6 BMTSYSP05 10.20.9.253 2016-04-13 12:01:57.563 1 05:53:03.979000
```

The 5th row belongs to a different group, so the time difference should not be `-1 day +06:25:41`, it has to be NaT. I need the difference logic to be applied for each grouping.

Any help would be appreciated !!

Answer (score 0):

After calling `reset_index()`, `df2` is not of type `pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy` any longer. It's a plain `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame` and you have no longer the ability to operate on groups as there are simply no groups any more, just a plain DataFrame.

In short, when you do this:

```
df2['timedif'] = df2['Date'].diff()
```

you are in fact running `diff()` on the entire series, the "un-grouped" series and this is why you get the values you get.

If this is your sample dataframe (after you've reset the index):

```
In [222]: df_sample
Out[222]: 
                  DateTime LocalIPAddress MachineName  count
0  2016-04-13 03:42:29.865    10.18.0.186   BMTSAFT04      1
1  2016-04-13 08:48:33.005    10.18.0.186   BMTSAFT04      1
2  2016-04-13 10:16:28.612    10.18.0.186   BMTSAFT04      1
3  2016-04-13 10:31:33.343    10.18.0.186   BMTSAFT04      1
4  2016-04-13 23:43:12.068    10.18.0.186   BMTSAFT04      1
5  2016-04-13 06:08:53.584    10.20.9.253   BMTSYSP05      1
6  2016-04-13 12:01:57.563    10.20.9.253   BMTSYSP05      1
```

In your description you're saying at some point:

> The 5th row belongs to a different group

In fact, before resetting the index, all sample rows are in different groups as you're grouping by many different columns. However, I'm going  to assume you meant to have grouped by `MachineName` in this case and I will group by `MachineName` here.

```
In [227]: df_sample.groupby('MachineName').apply(lambda x: x.DateTime.diff())
Out[227]: 
MachineName   
BMTSAFT04    0               NaT
             1   05:06:03.140000
             2   01:27:55.607000
             3   00:15:04.731000
             4   13:11:38.725000
BMTSYSP05    5               NaT
             6   05:53:03.979000
Name: DateTime, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: @user3447653 Was that at all helpful to what you were trying to do?